# php readfile() gives error 500 on some video files only

Tags: php, readfile, http-status-code-500

I have a problem with displaying some videos via a php script using readfile(). Some videos give a HTML status 500, others work fine. Something I do wrong, but I have no idea what. Can somebody hint me in the right direction? What might be the reason for error 500 ?

This is a simplified example I tested on my localhost to reproduce the error.

calling script:

```
<?php
  $videofiles=array("1.mp4", "2.mp4", "3.mp4", "4.mp4");
  for ($i=0; $i < count($videofiles); $i++) {
?>
    <div class="videos">
    <video controls>
        <source src="video.php?v=<?php echo $videofiles[$i]; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

delivering script video.php:

```
<?php
  $video=$_GET['v'];  
  header("Content-Type: video/mp4"); 
  header("Content-Length: ".filesize($video));
  readfile($video);
?>
```

All rights are set correct (if I replace "video.php?v=..." by the direct filepath all videos show). I suspect that it has to do with file size - the larger (> 150MB) are those who do not show, but I don't know... for testing I used videos from the same mobile phone and of the same day without altering them.

Comment: check your logs and enable error reporting

Comment: Any change if you run ob_end_flush(); before readfile?

Comment: Paste this piece of code on top of the file & execute. ```error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');``` It'll show you exact error message whatever you are getting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1

Comment: Although this does not answer your question, I have serious doubts about your video.php - why don't you serve those files directly without PHP? Your serving script really isn't of any use here.

Comment: @maio290 Of course in the given example it doesn't make sense to use readfile() . I made this simplified example to not cluster the question with my personal use and to reduce it to the real problem: why it produces error 500. I think it would only inflate the question if I added, for example, the testing of the $_GET input, the file locations and the  where and why etc. All that - in this case - would not have helped to illustrate the problem that I had.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers!

I found in the error log:

```
PHP
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
allocate 138174464 bytes)
```

After that I inserted in the script

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '400M' );
```

this solved the problem.